# Quick Desktop Components

Tags: qt, plugins, desktop

I tried to install Qt Quick Desktop Components,
but I got an error like:

> module "QtDesktop" plugin "styleplugin" not found

```
 import QtDesktop 0.1 
 ^
```

Can anyone help me with that please?